# How to select a particular record by ID to delete it from the List?

Tags: html, reactjs, api, sharepoint

I have fetched some records to display from an API using React.
This is it how it looks when I fetch it.
[image: FetchData]

This is the code regarding it.

```
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    
      const handleChange = () => {
        setChecked(!checked);
        console.log(checked); 
      };  

<div className="users">
            {users.map((user) => {
              return (
                <div className="users" key={user.Id} >
                  <label> 
                  <p>
                  <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
                    Name: {user.Title}, EmpID: {user.EmpID}, ID: {user.Id}{" "}
                  <button onClick={() => handleClick(user.Id)} className="">
                    Delete    
                  </button>
                  </p>
                  </label>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when I click on any checkboxes, their respective ID gets selected, which then clicking on a General Delete Button (yet to be created) like Fetch and Reset, deletes the selected records by their respective IDs.
Here is the challenge, I am not able to retrieve the selected IDs by selecting the checkboxes. I just want to get all the selected checkboxes i.e., selected IDs in order to further delete it.

Fetched data looks something like this in the console :
[image: FetchDataInConsole]

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: could you please post all codes to see where you save your users list after fetch it ?

Comment: I store it in `users`  after fetching it by using useState();
`const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);`

Comment: check the answer below and adapt it with your code try to gorget anything ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a state array for the selected users to check/uncheck the checkbox
Once you click delete it will set the users list with users that doesn't exist in the selected users state.

```js
const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState([]);
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]) // i suppose you have this state to stock your list

const handleChange = (id) => {
  if(selectedUsers.findIndex(el => el ===id) !== -1) setSelectedUsers([...selectedUsers, id]); // if id deosn't exist we add it
  else {
    // if id exist delete it to uncheck the checkbox
    const newSelected = selectedUsers.filter((item) => item !== id)
    setSelectedUsers(newSelected);
  } 
};  

const handleDelete = () => {
  // set users with the old list without the selected ones
  const newUsers = users.filter((user) => selectedUsers.findIndex(ele => ele === user.Id) !== -1)
  setUsers(newUsers)
};  

// here where your rerset and fetch button you add this button
<button onClick={() => handleDelete()} className="">
              Delete    
            </button>
<div className="users">
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <div className="users" key={user.Id} >
            <label> 
            <p>
            <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={users.findIndex(el => el === user.Id) !== -1} 
        onChange={()=> handleChange(user.Id)}
      />
              Name: {user.Title}, EmpID: {user.EmpID}, ID: {user.Id}{" "}
            </p>
            </label>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: When I am clicking in my Fetch button, this error pops up in the console. 
`Uncaught TypeError: 1 is not a function` on this line : `checked={users.findIndex(user.Id) !== -1}`

Comment: I fixed it check again it should work fine now ^^              
 checked={users.findIndex(el => el === user.Id) !== -1}

Comment: Thanks a lot @Borni.Mr
I have used a different approach, I have stored the Ids in an array, which I will later use in my deleteData() to delete the records by sending it to the API.